# Error when running job using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I have  SQL Server 2008R2 installed on my Windows server 2008.
I created a package using the Import and Export Wizard from file system.
After that I created a job (SQL Agent Job ) that used the SSIS package I created in the first step.

After I run this job I would receive the following error:

> Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step
>   Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message
>   ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
>   10/10/2017 17:38:12,update job,Error,0,DBServer\ABC,update job,(Job
>   outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User
>   mydomain\myuser.  The last step to run was step 1 (update step
>   1).,00:00:10,0,0,,,,0 10/10/2017 17:38:12,update
>   job,Error,1,DBServer\ABC,update job,update job,,Executed as user:
>   mydomain\myuser$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility 
>   Version 10.0.6000.29 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp
>   1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  5:38:12 PM  Error:
>   2017-10-10 17:38:17.80     Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Drop table(s)
>   SQL Task 1 Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire
>   connection "DestinationConnectionAdoNET". Connection may not be
>   configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.  End Error  Error: 2017-10-10 17:38:17.81     Code:
>   0xC00291EC     Source: Preparation SQL Task 1 Execute SQL Task
>   Description: Failed to acquire connection
>   "DestinationConnectionAdoNET". Connection may not be configured
>   correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  5:38:12 PM  Finished: 5:38:17 PM 
>   Elapsed:  5.578 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step
>   failed.,00:00:10,0,0,,,,0

I did some research and I found that the SSIS service was not installed.
I installed SSIS and I can connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio.
After that I created new job using same file but still I received same error as before.
Please advise how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

So the SSIS service has been installed, but is it actually running?  Also, make sure that the domain and username are the same as those you used to setup the service.  You need to check the permissions settings for the database and server you are trying to configure.